# TVanimationsGestures Sample code Bug/Weird Behavior Overlapping Cells

Tags: iphone, accordion, overlap, sample, uitableview

Im trying to implement a nice accordion effect on my app. My goal is to "open up" a cell when the user tap on it, diplaying additionnal content (such as text) as the cell height increase.
The perfect sample code for that is the TableView Animations & Gestures sample code provided by Apple. However I am experiencing a strange behavior, that ruins the whole effect.

It appears that depending on the order in which the tableview will display its cells (top --> Bottom or Bottom-->up) the cells textviews will overlap each other or not.
As its a bit difficult to explain with word so here is it with images.

Those screenshots were taken from the TVAnimationsGestures Sample Code, without any changes made to it. It comes from the first version of the sample code without storyboard:

[image: Normal Behavior]

Now the version with the storyboard, first behaved well, but after a while, and without me touching the code it started drawing this :

[image: Overlapping cells]

And I have the exact problem on my custom with my custom cells.

It took me a while to understand what I think the problem comes from. If cells are drawn from the Top cell to the bottom, there is no such problem. However if cells are drawn bottom to the top, they will stack in reverse and therefore overlap each other. I don't think it is possible to control this behavior. 
What gave me the hint, is that when I scroll down, forcing the top cell to redraw, they actually redraw nicely, and the screen looks like this:

[image: Mixture]

A Mixture of overlapping cells and "good" cells.

Again, this all comes directly from Apple sample code, without any changes.
Does anyone knows whats going on?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the cell height by pinching on the cell.

Comment: It seems that the author of the question is looking for a programming solution. Or do I misunderstand the question?